# wrong result from left shift in java

Tags: java

I have made a variable in java, `byte a = 0xA6; //10100110`
then I made this :

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString( ((short)a<<8)&0xFFFF ));
```

The result is 0xA600. This is the right result. But when i tried

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString( ((short)a<<3)&0xFFFF ));
```

The expected result should be : 0x530 (10100110000)
but I got 0xFD30(1111110100110000) Emm... Can somebody explain how I got that wrong result...??

thanks... :-)

Comment: Please, show how exactly you initialize a variable.

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question? If not, you can mark answer as accepted and/or upvote it.

Comment: Eeh... sorry Kao, I have tried to upvote, but my reputation is not enough for that :-)

Answer (score 1):

The byte value `A6` represents a negative number (bytes are signed in Java). When you cast to a `short` it gets sign extended to `FFA6`. Moreover the shift operation is executed with integer values so it is again sign extended to `FFFFFFA6`. Shift left by three bits gives `FFFFFD30` and taking the lower 16 bits gives `0000FD30`.

This does not matter if you shift by 8 bits because you shift out and mask the additional 1 bits.

Comment: Thank you for your expalanation. So Should I make this ((short)a&0xFF<<3)0xFFF....???

umm.... I'm gonna try it then. ^_^

Comment: Better use `(a&0xff)<<3`

Answer (score 0):

When you declare initialize byte variable you have to downcast it from integer:

```
byte a = (byte) 0xA6;
```

So, instead of 10100110 you've got 11111111111111111111111110100110.

And, beacuse of this left shift works in that way:

```
 ((short)a<<8)&0xFFFF
```

returns 1010011000000000

```
 ((short)a<<3)&0xFFFF
```

returns 1111110100110000

Comment: So... Umm.. How do I get the right result from a<<a ?

Comment: just declare `a` as `int a = 0xA6;`

Comment: I can't make a as int, because the initial data is byte. So I have to cast to short :-)

Comment: Then cast it to short :)  `short a = (short)  0xA6;`